# SBT unresolved dependancy to maxmind

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt, maxmind

I am getting "unresolved dependency" when I add this line to my SBT file:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sanoma.cda" %% "maxmind-geoip2-scala" % "1.3.2"
```

This is the error that I get:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sanoma.cda#maxmind-geoip2-scala
_2.10;1.3.2: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1223)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1221)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1
244)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1
242)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sanoma.cda#m
axmind-geoip2-scala_2.10;1.3.2: not found
```

I am using IntelliJ 14 IDE

Is there a way of solving it?

Comment: See the [README](https://github.com/Sanoma-CDA/maxmind-geoip2-scala#installation). Have you tried to clone this project then `sbt +publish-local`?

Comment: @Dimitri is right. It looks like they don't have this in maven central, which is where the default resolver points

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri. I did some steps to resolve this issue, but the problem still remains. Please read the comment I wrote below.

Comment: check that the version you are publishing is indeed 1.3.2, because the latest is 1.5.1

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this library is not available in any major repository, so you will have to add manually to your local repo.

To make it work, first clone the repo: `https://github.com/Sanoma-CDA/maxmind-geoip2-scala`, then inside the project directory run: `sbt +publish-local`

Go back to your project and refresh its dependencies. You should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did the following: git clone https://github.co
m/snowplow/scala-maxmind-geoip then change to the directory: mamind and run: sbt +publish-local. Then I refreshed on IntelliJ my SBT file, but the problem seems to remain. Maybe the problem is related to the fact that I installed SBT that I downloaded and I have SBT on the IntelliJ?

Comment: Did you open SBT toolwindow (on the right side of IDE) and press refresh button?